# Understanding the code to write an overload function (new int[] in matrix operations)

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, operator-overloading

yesterday our lecturer got us this code below without any meaningful explanation. We are struggling to understand how it works.

```
class Matrix {
    static int mem;
    int rows, cols;
    int* ptr;

public:
Matrix(int l = 10, int k = 10) :rows(l), cols(k) {
    ptr = new int[rows * cols];
    mem += (rows * cols) * sizeof(int);
}

Matrix(const Matrix& x) :rows(x.rows), cols(x.cols) {
    ptr = new int[rows * cols];
    int* tmp = ptr;  // HERE
    mem += (rows * cols) * sizeof(int);
    for (int i = 0; i < x.rows * x.cols; i++) {
        ptr[i] = x.ptr[i];
    }
}

~Matrix() {
    mem -= (rows * cols) * sizeof(int);
    delete[] ptr;
}

friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, Matrix& x) {
    int* tmp = x.ptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < x.cols; j++) {
            input >> *tmp; tmp++;
        }
    }
    return input;
}

friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, Matrix& x) {
    int* tmp = x.ptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < x.cols; j++) {
            output << *tmp << " "; tmp++;
        }
        output << endl;
    }
    return output;
}

friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix& x, const Matrix& y) {
    Matrix tmp(x.rows,x.cols);
    if (x.rows != y.rows || x.cols != y.cols) {
        return tmp;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < x.rows * x.cols; i++) {
            tmp.ptr[i] = x.ptr[i] + y.ptr[i];
        }
        return tmp;
    }
}


Matrix operator=(const Matrix& x) {
    if (x.rows != x.cols) {
        delete[] ptr;
        rows = x.rows;
        cols = x.cols;
        ptr = new int[rows * cols];
        mem += (rows * cols) * sizeof(int);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < x.rows * x.cols; i++) {
        ptr[i] = x.ptr[i];
    }
    return *this;
}

friend Matrix operator*(const Matrix& x, const Matrix& y) {...}
};
```

Based on this chunk of code **we have to overload '*' operator** that would multiply two matrices together (ex. C = A * B).
And when it's fairly easy to do with 2D arrays, I just can't wrap my head around the way it's working right now, so any help would be more than appreciated.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The lecturer forgot `mem -= (rows * cols) * sizeof(int);` before `delete[] ptr;` in the assignment operator. Where do you stuck? I believe you don't need to teach C++ from the beginning.

Comment: Teaching people to use `operator new[]` to solve generic programs in 2021 is frankly quite bad. You should basically never need to use `operator new` or `operator new[]` unless your are doing super advanced stuff or implementing the STL. While it might not help you to solve your assignment, the correct and modern approach would be to use a `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` or even better a `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: _"it's fairly easy to do with 2D arrays, I just can't wrap my head around the way it's working right now"_ - in C (and then C++) fixed size 2D arrays are very weird. A variable of type `T[N][M]` behaves like a `T[N*M]`, and not an array of pointers, i.e., the elements are all consequential, and the last element of line N is just before the first of line N + 1. Thus, doing `x[3][4]` is somewhat like doing `*(&x[0][0] + (3*N + 4))`. You can do the same with your own array to access to T[x][y].

Comment: @mcilloni OK, that opened my eyes! Thanks so much for your replies!

Comment: BTW, that `Matrix operator=(.....)` looks wrong. First, it should return a reference. Then, it checks if `x` is a non-square matrix? Why should that matter? The test should be something else. Further, it's not exception safe: if `new` fails, the previous matrix is lost. Perhaps here I'd use the copy-and-swap idiom, instead.

Comment: @chi yes, that `operator=` is a mess. Some lecturers think that by omitting "complex" stuff like vectors their pupils would learn more about the basics, but they very often only end up confusing students and making a fool of themselves. First, because the fact you have `operator new` means you also have the C++ library at your disposal, and second, because with a `std::vector<T>` copying and moving this class would have been mostly trivial.